# file exists but will not load?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsfilemanager

I have added a resource (blue folder) to my resource bundle and all seems well even to the point where I use NSFileManger to determine if the files exists and if it does to print out the full path used in the check which it does like so:

```
NSString *p = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/words/001", 
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *a = [p stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"001-1.png"];

UIImage *i;

if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:a]) {

  NSLog(@"file found ... %@", a);

  i = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:a];
}
else {

  NSLog(@"doh!");
} 

[iv setImage:i];
```

I get this output from the file exists check

/Users/phh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/3DAB4772-7251-4E39-8EA8-4AFE32DFB61A/MyApp.app/words/001/001-1.png

but the UIImage is always nil?  I just cant see what is going on here....

Help....?

Thanks

Comment: Where you get the image is nil?

Comment: Is your word and 001 folder in blue color?

Answer (score 1):

The return value for [`imageWithContentsOfFile:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile%3a) is

> A new image object for the specified
>   file, or nil if the method could not
>   initialize the image from the
>   specified file.

Are you certain that the file at that location is a valid image file?

Comment: Hi, yes because when I select it in XCode it displays the correct image.  I can also see it in the folder in Finder and open it in PS.  This is driving me crazy!  :-(

Comment: Although saying that I just copied another image I know works in the app....and it works!  I will have to double check the one that does not work??  Will let you know  thanks for the pointer BTW

Comment: DOH!!  I learned something new today re image files and PhotoShop.  Be careful when saving your images as although I saved with the .png extension they were in fact PhotoShop PSD files!  Hence the file .png existed, but IOS could not open it!  Thanks for your valuable pointer

Answer (score 1):

Try this out while passing on the image to i

```
 i = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"001-1.png" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"word/001"];
```

hAPPY cODING...